Time between key down and key up inaccurate
I am trying to measure the amount of time the spacebar is held down. I am measuring by taking the time of key down, and then subtracting the key up time. For some reason, the time is unreasonably short, and the time is inverted (the longer its held, the shorter the time it says). Would anyone be able to determine why the time exported is inaccurate?
Tried googling, using chatgpt and checking previous forums. I implemented others code/fixes to similar issues but the bug persists.


let trialsLeft;
let lowerBound;
let upperBound;
let trialNumber = 1;
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,Trial,Duration,Target Time\n";
let spacebarDownTime;
let spacebarUpTime;
let randomNumber = 0;

function startCountdown() {

  document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';

  let countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
  let count = 5;
  countdownElement.textContent = 5;

  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    count--;
    countdownElement.textContent = count;

    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      displayRandomNumber();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function displayRandomNumber() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown); // Add event listener
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp); // Add keyup listener

  document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'block';
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound + 1)) + lowerBound;
  document.getElementById('page3').innerHTML =
    `
                <p>Trial number: ${trialNumber}</p>
                <h2>Number of seconds to hold the spacebar: ${randomNumber}</h2>
                <p>Press and hold the spacebar to record the duration.</p>
            `;
}

function handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    spacebarDownTime = new Date().getTime(); // Record time of key press

    const imageContainer = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
    document.getElementById('imageContainer').style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById('page3').innerHTML =
      `
                    <p>Trial number: ${trialNumber}</p>
                    <h2>Number of seconds to hold the spacebar: ${randomNumber}</h2>
                    <p>Press and hold the spacebar to record the duration.</p>
                `;
  }
}

function handleKeyUp(event) {
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    spacebarUpTime = new Date().getTime(); // Record time of key release

    document.getElementById('imageContainer').style.display = 'none';

    let duration = spacebarUpTime - spacebarDownTime;
    if (duration > 0) {
      saveData(trialNumber, duration);
    }
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown); // Add event listener
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp); // Add keyup listener
    nextAction(trialNumber);
  }
}

function nextAction(trialNumber) {
  if (trialNumber < trialsLeft) {
    document.getElementById('nextTrialContainer').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    displayExportButton(); // Show export options if trials are completed
  }
}

function saveData(trialNumber, duration) {
  csvContent += `${trialNumber},${duration/1000} seconds,${randomNumber} seconds\n`;
}

function nextTrial() {
  document.getElementById('nextTrialContainer').style.display = 'none';
  trialNumber++;
  if (trialNumber <= trialsLeft) {
    displayCountdown(); // Correct function call to start countdown
  } else {
    displayExportButton(); // Show export options if trials are completed

  }
}

function displayCountdown() {
  document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none'; // Hide page1
  document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'block'; // Ensure page2 is visible
  document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
  startCountdown(); // Initiate countdown
}

function displayExportButton() {
  document.getElementById('page1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('page2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('page3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('exportContainer').style.display = 'block';
}

function exportData() {
  const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute("download", "key_press_data.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}

function resetPage() {
  location.reload(); // Reload the page to reset everything
}

document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  trialsLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById('numTrials').value);
  lowerBound = parseInt(document.getElementById('lowerBound').value);
  upperBound = parseInt(document.getElementById('upperBound').value);

  if (isNaN(trialsLeft) || isNaN(lowerBound) || isNaN(upperBound)) {
    alert('Please enter valid numbers');
    return;
  }

  if (lowerBound >= upperBound) {
    alert('Upper bound must be greater than lower bound');
    return;
  }

  displayCountdown();
});

document.getElementById('exportBtn').addEventListener('click', exportData);
document.getElementById('resetBtn').addEventListener('click', resetPage);
document.getElementById('nextTrial').addEventListener('click', nextTrial);
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .container {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    #countdown {
      font-size: 24px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    #imageContainer {
      display: none;
    }
  <div class="container">
    <div id="page1">
      <h2>Enter Details</h2>
      <label for="numTrials">Number of Trials:</label>
      <input type="number" id="numTrials" min="1" required>
      <br>
      <label for="lowerBound">Lower Bound Time (seconds):</label>
      <input type="number" id="lowerBound" min="1" required>
      <br>
      <label for="upperBound">Upper Bound Time (seconds):</label>
      <input type="number" id="upperBound" min="1" required>
      <br>
      <button id="startButton">Start</button>
    </div>

    <div id="page2" style="display: none;">
      <h2>Countdown</h2>
      <div id="countdown">5</div>
    </div>

    <div id="page3" style="display: none;">
      <p>Trial number: <span id="trial"></span></p>
      <h2>Number of seconds to hold the spacebar: <span id="random"></span></h2>
      <p>Press and hold the spacebar to record the duration.</p>

    </div>

    <div id="exportContainer" style="display: none;">
      <button id="exportBtn">Export Data</button>
      <br>
      <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div id="imageContainer" style="display: none;">
      <img src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/53/15/25/360_F_353152513_w2u3qD8i3aexYr07t2TIjIOZnftclZ7X.jpg" width="75" height="75">
    </div>

    <div id="nextTrialContainer" style="display: none;">
      <button id="nextTrial">Next Trial</button>
    </div>

  </div>




Is all that code needed to measure the time between space down and space up? Could you please reduce it to just that?

I am measuring by taking the time of key down, and then subtracting the key up time. <-- Times, represented as numbers, get bigger the farther into the future you get, so you should be subtracting the key down time (the smaller number) from the key up time (the larger number).

Does this answer your question? How to get info on what key was pressed on for how long?

Your problem is with auto key repeat. You are continually setting your spacebarDownTime every handful of milli-seconds with the repeated keydown events.
You can use the event.repeat property to deal with that. Simple fix is to change the if() statement at the top of your keydown event handler to be:

if (event.key === ' ' && !event.repeat) {


Thanks! This did the trick, appreciate you taking the time to nail it down!
